# How to configure Apache Nutch to ignore certain url patterns

Tags: nutch

I am crawling a website using Apache Nutch. While crawling, I want nutch to ignore multiple url patterns like http://www.youtube.com/..so on..., http://www.twitter.com/so on.., etc.

I know how to configure regex-urlfilter.txt file to crawl specific url.

But I dont know how to configure nutch to ignore certain url patterns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed following url and found many  useful examples

https://scm.thm.de/pharus/nutch-config/blobs/66fba7d3dc015974b5c194e7ba49da60fe3c3199/Nutch-Config/conf/regex-urlfilter.txt

Comment: The link is dead the sense that it redirects to the homepage.